Prevent HtmlWebpackPlugin from injecting unsused `<script>` tags
I have a problem where chunks split out by SplitChunksPlugin are being injected into HTML files that does not use them.
In my config, there are 2 entry points main and jira_callback, and one HtmlWebpackPlugin instance for each of them. main imports some libraries, and jira_callback doesn't at all (literally 0 import statements). Libraries are split into a separate chunk using SplitChunksPlugin, but this chunk is getting injected into the HTML output of jira_callback even if it doesn't need it.
How do I make sure the library chunk is only injected into main?
Here is my webpack.common.js:
'use strict';

import path from 'node:path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import CssMinimizerPlugin from 'css-minimizer-webpack-plugin';
import CopyPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';

const __dirname = import.meta.dirname;

export default {
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.js',
    jira_callback: './src/jira-callback/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/i,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                {
                  useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                  corejs: '3.37',
                  targets: 'defaults',
                  bugfixes: true,
                },
              ],
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: ['...', new CssMinimizerPlugin()],
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          name: 'vendor',
          test: /(node_modules|bower_components)[/\\](?!exceljs)/,
          priority: -10,
        },
      },
      chunks: 'all',
    },
    removeAvailableModules: true,
    sideEffects: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      chunks: ['main'],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/jira-callback/index.html',
      filename: 'jira-callback/index.html',
      chunks: ['jira_callback'],
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          context: './src',
          from: './**/*.php',
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets',
      'jquery-ui-css': 'jquery-ui/../../themes/base',
    },
  },
};

P.S. Ignore the janky mix of php and nodejs... I have no choice but to work with it.

You can try to use modern html-bundler-webpack-plugin instead of HtmlWebpackPlugin.
Using the html-bundler-webpack-plugin:

an entry point is any HTML template
source files of JavaScript and SCSS/CSS can be specified directly in HTML:

<link href="./style.scss" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="./main.js" defer="defer"></script>
No longer need to define source JavaScript files in Webpack entry.


inlines JS, CSS into HTML

In your case, you can define source JavaScript files in HTML using <script > tag anywhere, e.g.:
./src/index.html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- relative path to SCSS source file -->
    <link href="./style.scss" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- relative path to ./src/index.js -->
    <script src="./index.js" defer="defer"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Homepage</h1>
  </body>
</html>

./src/jira-callback/index.html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- relative path to SCSS source file -->
    <link href="./style.scss" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Jira Callback</h1>
    <!-- define the source JS where you need it -->
    <!-- relative path to ./src/jira-callback/index.js -->
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

The source JavaScript files defined in templates will be resolved, automatically processed via Webpack loaders.
In generated HTML the source files will be replaced with correct output URLs.
If you use the SplitChunksPlugin, then this plugin add only really needed generated JS chunks (index.js, runtime.chunk.js, etc.), but not all generated chunks.
Webpack config:
'use strict';

import path from 'node:path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlBundlerPlugin from 'html-bundler-webpack-plugin';
import CssMinimizerPlugin from 'css-minimizer-webpack-plugin';
import CopyPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';

const __dirname = import.meta.dirname;

export default {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      // entrypoint is the HTML template,
      // SCSS and JS dependencies can be defined directly in HTML
      entry: [
        // add here your pages
        {
          import: 'src/index.html',
          filename: 'index.html',
        },
        {
          import: 'src/jira-callback/index.html',
          filename: 'jira-callback/index.html',
        },
      ],
      js: {
        filename: '[name].js', // JS output filename
      },
      css: {
        filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css', // CSS output filename
      },
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          context: './src',
          from: './**/*.php',
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/i,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                {
                  useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                  corejs: '3.37',
                  targets: 'defaults',
                  bugfixes: true,
                },
              ],
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: ['...', new CssMinimizerPlugin()],
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          name: 'vendor',
          test: /(node_modules|bower_components)[/\\](?!exceljs)/,
          priority: -10,
        },
      },
      chunks: 'all',
    },
    removeAvailableModules: true,
    sideEffects: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets',
      'jquery-ui-css': 'jquery-ui/../../themes/base',
    },
  },
};

You can create a small repo on GitHub with your use case and I can help you configure it.

My current config uses webpack-merge to define different the output filenames for JS files (output.filename) depending on developement or production mode. How can I do that with this plugin?

You can use output.filename instend of js.filename option.
If the js.filename plugin option is not defined, the default output.filename option is used.
The js.filename and css.filename plugin options are to keep all relevant options in one place.
